# How to call strings from different methods into the main method

Tags: c#

I have been trying to experiment with methods and I wanted to use the strings Nom and Cm in the main method but they had already been used in different methods. There was an error that it was "non existent" and now I am unsure of how I would be able to call the strings into the main method.

```
using System;


namespace Main
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            YourName();
            Height();
            
            Console.WriteLine($"Well {Nom}, are {Cm}cm tall ");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void YourName()
        {
            Console.Write("What is your name? ");
            string Nom;
            Nom = Console.ReadLine();
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Nom))
            {
                Console.Write("Be that way. ");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Write("That's a great name! ");
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        
        private static void Height()
        {
            double Inch;
            double Cm;
            Console.Write("How tall are you in inches?: ");
            Inch = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

            Cm = Inch * 2.54;

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Those are [local variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/variables)

You need to return the variables to the calling methods (make sure to change the method signature)

```
    private static String YourName()
    {
        Console.Write("What is your name? ");
        string Nom;
        Nom = Console.ReadLine();
        ... 
        return Nom;
    }
```

Then

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var Nom = YourName();
        Console.WriteLine($"Hello {Nom}");
    }
```

---

One alternative is to use static, class-level variables

```
class Program
{
    static String Nom;
    static double CM;

    // ... functions here
```

And remove the variable declarations in the methods, however, this pattern should be avoided unless you have instance (non-static) variables

Comment: Oh I see, sorry I am a beginner and I forgot that you have to return variables. Thanks for the help!